# Rounded corners of <img/> element in Opera browser

Tags: css, xhtml, opera, clip

I have implemented rounded corners for  html elements as it is written in [this article](http://www.boogdesign.com/b2evo/index.php/firefox-img-rounded-corners-svg?blog=2) (final result of that article you can see [here](http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/svg/rounded-corners-2.html)). Everything was ok, but! it doesn't work in Opera browser. While Opera developers say that their browser has the best of all support for clip CSS properties and for SVG.

Please help, what is the problem in that example? (mime types, svg version, etc.?)

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Opera? Opera uses the CSS3-compliant (no-prefix) `border-radius` property. At any rate, that article says nothing about that technique working in Opera.

Comment: None of browsers apply border-radius CSS3 property to images. That's why we have to make tricks :)

Comment: I could use background-image, but it is very uncomfortable in my current situation

Comment: @artyom.stv - they do apply the style; it's just that foreground content is always allowed to overflow the rounded corners if necessary.

Comment: @Spudley - but overflow:hidden doesn't change things. what do you mean saying that they do apply the style (example?) ?

Comment: @artyom.stv: what I mean is that `border-radius` doesn't clip the foreground content. If you have images or text in the corners, they will be displayed even though they are outside of box's border. Try adding `border: solid black 1px;` to the style, alongside `border-radius` and you'll see that the corners of the border disappear where they curve behind the image. A `<div>` with text in the corners works the same: have a big border-radius, the text will also be displayed over the top of the rounded edges. That's the way it works. `border-radius` only clips the background, not the foreground.

Comment: So therefore, the correct solution is to use `background-image` rather than an `<image>` tag. Maybe uncomfortable, but that's the solution.

Comment: @Spudley - thank you for explaination about border-radius. And what is about clip-path CSS property? I thought it should work well everywhere... It works in FF, but for unknown reason doesn't work in Opera. Any ideas?

Comment: @artyom.stv: well, it is a bit of a hack, and the article author even says it'll only work in Firefox, so it's probably only really useful as a proof of concept.

Comment: @artyom.stv: I note that Firefox 4 has resolved the issue by making the `overflow` property respect the `border-radius`. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=459144

Comment: Thanks to everybody! Will have to use background-image though :)

Comment: About the 'clip-path' property, that works in SVG content only at the moment, but might work in HTML too in the future. There's no W3C specification (yet) that defines the behavior except for the SVG case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer so far is "no. You can't.".
It is a recorded bug in Opera Bugs DB.

SVG is one possible hack, there is a [tool for rounded corners](http://a.deveria.com/roundgen/) to help you get it right